# How to extract text between xml tags?

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

One of my inputs, is an xml string:

`<element1 attrib1="a1"><element2>text</element2></element1>`

I can extract attribute values with

```
    <field name="attrib1" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="element1/@attrib1"/>
    </field>
```

but I can't get Jasper to return the value between `<element2>...</element2>` I've tried:

```
    <field name="element2" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="element1/element2"/>
    </field>
```

and

```
    <field name="element2" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="element1/element2/"/>
    </field>
```

and

```
    <field name="element2" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="element1/element2/text()"/>
    </field>
```

but when I call it out with `$F{element2}`, Jasper just inserts `$F{element2}`, and does not evaluate the expression.

Comment: instead of `element1/element2/` or `element1/element2` use `element1/element2/text()`

Comment: I apologize, I got it backwards - Jasper prints the field name (`element2`) in either case, text() does not affect this behavior

Comment: It seems Jasper is simply not evaluating the `$F{}` expression for some reason

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can use this field declaration:

```
<field name="element2Value" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="/element1/element2"/>
</field>
```

It means that the right expression is: `/element1/element2`

### The working example

The full jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="XPathExample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="two_level_xml"/>
    <queryString language="XPath">
        <![CDATA[*]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="element2Value" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.field.expression" value="/element1/element2"/>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="30">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{element2Value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I used this datasource adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xmlDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.xml.XmlDataAdapterImpl">
    <name>two_level_xml</name>
    <dataFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="repositoryDataLocation">
        <location>C:\path\simple_xml.xml</location>
    </dataFile>
    <useConnection>true</useConnection>
    <namespaceAware>false</namespaceAware>
    <selectExpression/>
    <locale xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">ru_RU</locale>
    <timeZone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com" xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">Europe/Moscow</timeZone>
</xmlDataAdapter>
```

and this xml:

```
<element1 attrib1="a1">
    <element2>text</element2>
</element1>
```

### Result

The generated result (output) at the JSS:

[image: Output generated via JSS]